# Circumscribe only 1 digit

Tags: animation, math, manim

So I have this table and I want to circumscribe only 1 digit of each real number, in this way:

0,**1**56739345...
0,8**2**3478901...
0,46**5**809217...
0,156**4**39345...
0,8234**7**8903...

but I don't know how use the animation class Circumscribe() only to circumscribe a part of a MathTex class.

[Table with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktjaN.png)

Anyway, here's my code:

```
class SimpleAnimation(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = MobjectTable([
            [MathTex(r"\mathbb{N}"), Tex(r"$\mathbb{R}$")],
            [MathTex(r"1"), MathTex(r"0,156739345...")],
            [MathTex(r"2"), MathTex(r"0,823478901...")],
            [MathTex(r"3"), MathTex(r"0,465809217...")],
            [MathTex(r"4"), MathTex(r"0,156439345...")],
            [MathTex(r"5"), MathTex(r"0,823478903...")],
            [MathTex(r"\vdots"), MathTex(r"\vdots")]
            ],
            v_buff=0.2,
            h_buff=1.2)
        self.add(table)
```

I already tried to search for this but with no results

Answer (score 2):

The table object has a method `.get_rows()` which returns a list of "rows", being each row a tuple containing the objects in the cells. In this case, each row has two cells, and thus `row[0]` and `row[1]` will be the contents of these cells.

The cell of interest is then `row[1]`, and it is a `MathTex` object. These objects contain a single submobject (accessible then via `row[1][0]`) which contains in turn the list of symbols that draw the formula. Each symbol is accessible via its own index, that in this case would be `row[1][0][0]` for the first symbol (the "0"), `row[1][0][1]` for the second symbol (the comma), and so on.

So you can access any individual digit knowing its index which in this case starts at 2 because the two previous symbols were the "0" and the comma.

You can write a loop which prepares a list of `Circunscribe()` animations, for each of these digits. Then you can play that list of animations via an `AnimationGroup`, which gives you control on the lag_ratio for some nice effects.

Final code:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        table = MobjectTable([
            [MathTex(r"\mathbb{N}"), Tex(r"$\mathbb{R}$")],
            [MathTex(r"1"), MathTex(r"0,156739345...")],
            [MathTex(r"2"), MathTex(r"0,823478901...")],
            [MathTex(r"3"), MathTex(r"0,465809217...")],
            [MathTex(r"4"), MathTex(r"0,156439345...")],
            [MathTex(r"5"), MathTex(r"0,823478903...")],
            [MathTex(r"\vdots"), MathTex(r"\vdots")]
            ],
            v_buff=0.2,
            h_buff=1.2)
        self.add(table)
        self.wait()
        index = 2
        animations = []
        for row in table.get_rows()[1:-1]: # Skip header and last row
            animations.append(Circumscribe(row[1][0][index]))
            index+=1
        self.play(AnimationGroup(*animations, lag_ratio=0.3), run_time=5)
        self.wait()
```

which produces this result:

[image: Result]

Comment: tysm <3 you saved  a ton of time